# send data to php file using ajax and jquery and display the result to iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

I'm trying to send data to php file then to display result to Iframe,

but with no success...

below my jquery part :

```
  $( ".load_message" ).click(function() {
        //On marque uniquement l'id de l'expediteur et du destinataire
        // pour chercher les messages expédiés par A vers B ou inversement
        var from = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.from').text();
        var to = $(this).closest('tr').find('span.to').text();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'pages_ajax/fetch-messages.php',
            data: { from: from,  to: to},
            dataType: "json"
        });
        //reload all iFrames
        $('iframe').each(function() {
              this.contentWindow.location.reload(true);
        });
    });
```

Then in the Iframe (php file)

I've got this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../../lib_php/librairie.php");
require_once("../../config/connexion.php");
//header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');

/**
 * Fonction qui retourne une liste de messages
 * @return int
 */
function fetchMessages() {
    if (isset($_POST['from'])) {
        $from = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['from']);
        $to = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['to']);

        $query = "SELECT `id`, `from`, `to`, `message`, `sent`, `read`, `direction` 
    FROM `cometchat` 
    WHERE `from` = {$from} || `from` = {$to} || `to` = {$to} || `to` = {$from}";

        return $query;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

$liste_messages = fetchMessages();
if (!is_null($liste_messages)):
    $result_message = mysql_query($query);
    while ($mess = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_message)):
        ?>

        ici
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

the trouble I have is that Iframe is not reaload, and results are not displaying

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: Why would you use ajax to update iframe's that are then reloaded, when you can update the actual page instead ?

Comment: You shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code since they are deprecated. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead

Comment: it is because I want to execute a loop, in jquery I only know how to out some var and to apply them to fill fields or span, but this time this is a query that I need to loop

Comment: javascript: for item in items { }

Comment: Your iframe reload is probably running before your ajax call finishes. Try adding it (or as a callback function) in ajax.success

Comment: I addes this code ` setInterval(refreshIframe1, 1000);
       function refreshIframe1() {
           $("#messages")[0].src = $("#messages")[0].src;
       } ` but I think it may be the wrong method, because it reload the entire pages. I just want to have the request executed